# Rails and jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a text_field_tag,in rails, I have specified its id to the jquery-ui-datepicker. Everything works fine. But the value in the text field persists even after page refresh. Is there any solution to this?

```
<%= text_field_tag("meeting_filter_from") %>
```

Jquery Code:

```
jQuery('#meeting_filter_from').datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ready, have jquery clear the field:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#meeting_filter_from').val("");
    jQuery('#meeting_filter_from').datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy', showOn: 'both', buttonImage: '/images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true});
});
```