# Rails jquery datepicker in form_tag for search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For Forms which updates models my datepicker is working and included as follows:

```
= f.input :starts_at, :as => :datepicker
```

now I want to use the `Datepicker` in a Search Form which passes several search params to the controller (not using a model). I'm no sure how the input is defined with text_field_tag or else.

```
= form_tag some_action_path, method: "get", class: "someclass" do |f|
    = text_field_tag ???...
```

Comment: The solution on [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132179/rails-and-jquery-ui-datepicker) works well.  I believe it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution, i simply have to pass the paramname as id to the datepicker js

```
= text_field_tag :starts_at
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#starts_at" ).datepicker();
  })
```

Comment: Thanks @jethroo.. this is what i wanted..+1 for ur answer